# Missing argument for parameter when creating Swift Realm Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am creating a simple `User` object that inherits from `RealmSwift's` `Object`:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {

    @objc dynamic var userId: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var email: String = ""

convenience init(userId: String, email: String) {

    self.init()

    self.userId = userId
    self.email = email

}
```

When building, I receive the following error `Missing argument for parameter 'userId' in call`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please include the code actually causing the issue. How are you calling the initializer?

Answer (score 0):

Why use a convenience initializer? You can initialize Users with Realm's default initializer,

```
let user = User(value: ["userID": "1234", "email": "email@gmail.com"])
```

Comment: Error in your user class or somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you haven't written an initializer which accepts 0 arguments, but you are currently calling it...

You can remove the word "convenience", and change the line:

```
self.init()
```

to

```
super.init()
```

and the error will go away, and the object will be properly initialized.
This is because the superclass `Object` **does** have an initializer which takes no arguments.